# In Illustrator, is there a way smooth selected paths algorithmically?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, selections

I'm used to gimp in which there is a way to select a path and use an algorithm to remove excess points and generally smooth out the path.

It asks for details like what kind of edge to keep as a corner, and thresholds for removing and rounding out points.

Is there a way to do this in illustrator?  I've seen the smooth tool, but it seems strange there isn't a way to do it all at once coming up in any of my searches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Ryan's](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/59038/in-illustrator-is-there-a-way-smooth-selected-paths-algorithmically#comment87581_59038) and [Scott's](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/59038/in-illustrator-is-there-a-way-smooth-selected-paths-algorithmically#comment87582_59038) comments the feature you are looking for can be found under `Object -> Path -> Simplify...`

This will present you with the following dialog:

[image]

Here you are given some control over how it should simplify a path.

> **Curve Precision**
>
> Enter a value between 0% and 100% to set how closely the simplified
>   path should follow the original path. A higher percentage creates more
>   points and a closer fit. Any existing anchor points are ignored except
>   for endpoints of a curve and corner points (unless you enter a value
>   for Angle Threshold).
>
> **Angle Threshold**
>
> Enter a value between 0 and 180° to control the smoothness of corners.
>   If the angle of a corner point is less than the angle threshold, the
>   corner point is not changed. This option helps keep corners sharp,
>   even if the value for Curve Precision is low.
>
> **Straight Lines**
>
> Creates straight lines between the object’s original anchor points.
>   Corner points are removed if they have an angle greater than the value
>   set in Angle Threshold.
>
> **Show Original**
>
> Shows the original path behind the simplified path.

[Source](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/editing-paths.html#simplify_paths)

When you're happy with your options, hit apply. Here's an example of a simplified straight line with default settings:

[image]

Note that  if you're looking for more manual control there's also a tool called the `Smooth Tool` which essentially lets you draw over a path in order to smooth or simplify it by hand. [Click here for more information](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/editing-paths.html#smooth_paths).